# What's the best single CSS media query min-width to use to encompass all iPhone and Android phones?

Tags: android, iphone, css

For example, min-width:480px seems to be fine for all old and new iPhones. But I don't have an android phone and I think android may be a little bigger on average. So would I be better off using something like min-width:520px?

What is the best min-width to use?

Comment: It's really very hard to say, given the immense diversity of Android devices.

Comment: 540? 600? As long as it's not > 700/800 I think it's fine. But The lower the better so that it doesn't cut into the desktop viewing.

Answer (score 0):

I think a conservative min-width would be 240px. For more info on designing for multiple screen sizes, http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/effective-design-multiple-screen-sizes is a great resource.

Like boltclock said, there is an enormous variety of cell phone sizes. Luckily, android has an SDK (phone simulator) that works great. You can download the majority of the versions of the android OS and test on a variety of resolutions. Although it takes some time to install (my experience is on mac) especially if you're not so familiar with terminal.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

You should also check out Ripple which creates a pretty versatile mobile testing environment in chrome. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc